# What is the algorithm that R uses in data frame filtering?

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe

For example, I have a data frame, and I want to subset it according to specific conditions:

```
df[df$gender == "woman" & df$age > 40, ]
```

What is the algorithm behind this filtering in R?

Comment: I am guessing a regex search when it comes to character matching, and numeric comparison for the rest. These are base functions so you would have to look deep to get an answer.

Comment: Are you asking because you got an unexpected result, or because you are looking for performance improvements, or academic interest, or something else? Hard to answer well without more context.

Comment: @JonSpring, I am just curious to know. No special reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the execution of the code `df[df$gender == "woman" & df$age > 40, ]` the following happens:

1. `df$gender` extracted.
2. `df$gender == "woman"` evaluated, `boolean` vector returned.
3. `df$age` extracted.
4. `df$age > 40` evaluated, `boolean` vector returned.
5. Logical by-element `AND` applied to each element of vectors in Step 2 and Step 4.
6. Rows from `df` which have `TRUE` flag in Step 5 are extracted.

In all above cases backend `C\C++` functions are called. E.g. `[]` subset function calls for `do_subset` in [subset.c](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/subset.c).

You can study mapping between R functions and it's `C` back-end in [names.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3d8fc77d602f19c9722d8e13c1a1f5f69f42a5c4/src/main/names.c#L218)

For further details you can consult [Accessing R Source](https://github.com/jennybc/access-r-source)